# How to disable past dates of Kendo datepicker in angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am using kendo datepicker in my angular 2 application. I wanted to disable dates which is smaller than the present date.

```
  <kendo-datepicker  formControlName="departureValue"  [format]="'MMM-dd-yyyy'" (click)="ChangeReturnDate()"></kendo-datepicker>
```

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use the disableDates attribute like :

1. In [angular 1](http://dojo.telerik.com/iLEcO) ,
2. In angular 2 i tried try to look for the disableDates attribute( **i cant find in the [API ref](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/api/DatePickerComponent/), probably not available yet**)
3. Alternatively use the min value(**drawback are the past date will be hidden, not disabled like when we use disableDates**)

use it like :

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <p>Select a date:</p>
        <kendo-datepicker
            [min]="min"
            [(ngModel)]="value"
            #dateModel="ngModel"
        ></kendo-datepicker>
    </div>`
})

class AppComponent {
    public min: Date = new Date();
    public value: Date = new Date();
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow your approach for angularjs (1) by copying the exact same code from the dojo, but it didn't made any difference